# Creating custom factors in R

Tags: r, factors

If I create factors for single_panel$PanelID (dataframe) and obtain the levels, I get

```
levels(single_panel$PanelID)

[1] "210E0110" "240E100E" "250E1050" "250E1051" "250E1053" "250E1057" "250E105A" "250E105F"
[9] "250E1066"
```

I would like to creates custom levels by grouping the 9 into 5 categories

```
Road.Left =c("250E1050","250E1066"),
Road.Right =c("250E1053", "250E105A"),
Back.Left =c("250E1057","240E100E"), 
Back.Right =c("250E105F","250E1051")
Pyranometer =c("240E100E")
```

The way i thought this could be implemented was

```
levels(single_panel$PanelID, levels =( Road.Left =c("250E1050","250E1066"), Road.Right =c("250E1053", "250E105A"), Back.Left =c("250E1057","240E100E"), Back.Right =c("250E105F","250E1051")))
```

But this does not work.

The idea of creating factors was to plot data based on the factor variables

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution:

```
single_panel$newFactor <- with(single_panel, {
        (PanelID == "250E1050" | PanelID == "250E1066")*1 +
        (PanelID == "250E1053" | PanelID == "250E105A")*2 +
        (PanelID == "250E1057" | PanelID == "240E100E")*3 +
        (PanelID == "250E105F" | PanelID == "250E1051")*4 +
        (PanelID == "240E100E")*5
}

single_panel$newFactor <- factor(single_panel$newFactor,
                                 labels = c('Road.Left',
                                            'Road.Right',
                                            'Back.Left', 
                                            'Back.Right',
                                            'Pyranometer'))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, levels = 1:6 attribute is required in the factor